# Should I include marijuana retail on my resume?

Tags: resume, united-states, drug-test

My boyfriend and I live in Washington state.

He has been trying to get a new job, but is unsure if he should include his most recent job on his resume.  He worked part time at a Marijuana retail shop while working at Lowe’s full time.

Should he leave the shop off his resume even though it is entirely legal in our state, or put it on?

Comment: Is the store name obvious that it's a selling pot? Otherwise you can include it, describe all your duties and simply ommit the goods being sold, but also not deying it at all during interview.

Comment: Without asking for the name of the retail shop, does the shop name imply that it sells Marijuana, or could "Sales Associate at [shop name]" appear completely innocent?

Comment: rather blatant duplicate of [Should I put weed related job on my resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/91515/should-i-put-weed-related-job-on-my-resume)

Comment: @gnat the title might be similar, but the context is completely different. That question, and the other linked question there, both concern whether or not to include a technical achievement related to something illegal or disreputable. This question concerns an actual job working at a completely legal but controversial employer. Not to mention that accepted answer has absolutely no bearing here...

Comment: answer that is voted twice over accepted one gives a completely relevant advice

Comment: @gnat: If one answer is relevent, that doesn't mean the question is a "rather blatant duplicate".

Comment: no, per my reading of [this guidance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166707/165773) relevant answer means exactly that, duplicate

Comment: @gnat: As I read it, only one answer being relevant does not make the question duplicates (not thw same contenr is discussed there). Also, I think your post implies that one should explain in friendly ways why the other question helps - saying "rather blatant duplicate" when the question is different is in my view neither helpdul.nor friendly.

Comment: it's not just only one, some random answer - it is a top voted one, and I think much better addressing both this and duplicate question than accepted one. As for the imaginary un/friendliness I would like to remind that word "blatant" is used for many years in [official text of a close flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185873/165773) meaning it passed a fairly thorough scrutiny of network wide community in whole time it was used

Comment: @Caliver Maybe you don't live in Washington, but every pot shop name is extremely obvious

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim Now I had to look that up. Indeed, "Uncle Ike's Pot Shop", "Green Fire" or "Kush21" might ring a few bells

Answer (score 30):

**I think the risks outweigh the benefits**

1. There is no unemployment gap to fill. There is a full-time position at Lowes covering the same time period.
2. Employers often take a dim view of moonlighting. Some companies outright prohibit it. Others require you report it. Some are worried about sharing with competitors and others with problems scheduling you for shifts. Others are just worried about the employee being tired. Obviously retail is a lot less strict about this, but I am sure that scheduling conflicts are on the minds of those hiring.
3. It being legal gets rid of the idea that he is a criminal. It does not get rid of the idea that he is a pothead. It may be completely unfair, but that is what many imagine when they think of someone who works at a weed store. During periods of high unemployment, companies tend to get a lot more picky and are willing to exclude people based on smaller things.

Comment: Right. Looking at it the other way, what benefit does it add, even if it's positively received?

Comment: Also, it’s not legal, so there’s still that.

Comment: @jmoreno- It could be perfectly legal in Colorado but illegal in another state.  We’re not talking about potential federal employment where marijuana use is illegal

Answer (score 13):

This is a difficult question to answer because it is opinion-based and the reception/reaction to it being on a resume will vary widely.

For what it's worth, I would not include it unless:

It is relevant to the position that he is applying for.

OR

Not including it would cause a significant gap in his employment history.

Comment: I agree it is very hard to put a universal answer on this. I think it’s definitely worth the time to make both versions of the CV, and apply to each job with the one that seems more appropriate, given what you know about the position and the company’s culture.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, I would include it as it is relevant retail sales experience.

I would also add a note on the application or resume that it is indeed legal just to be 100% clear to people who are viewing it.

If he is applying for jobs in the **same state** chances are that employers are aware of its legality, so you may or may not include the "*100% legal*" statement in this case.

Comment: "2018-2019: Worked in a Mary Jane retail shop (100% LEGAL)" Sure does not look sketchy as hell.

Comment: Putting "100% LEGAL" anywhere on a resume says "I am a smartass, and the law is a jackass." If that is the message you want to send to the hiring department, go for it :)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the type of new job he is applying to. You could just leave it out, as some people would (incorrectly!) making a character judgement call.

Leaving it out would not result in any gaps in his working history, as you said he was working fulltime.

The plus point about leaving it in would be showing that he worked 2 jobs. And because it is legal it would make an interesting talking point when he does get an interview.